# Scala for the Impatient, chapter 2, exercise on recursive pow function

Tags: scala

I am reading Scala for the Impatient, Chapter 2 and there is an exercise question I don't understanding what exactly does it want:

> Write a function that computes x^n, where n is an integer. Use the
>   following recursive definition:
>
> - X^n = y * y if n is even and positive, where y = x^(n/2)
> - X^n = x * x^(n-1) if n is odd and positive
> - x^0 = 1
> - x^n = 1 / x^-n if n is negative

If the question want x^n, I could just use the pow method defined in scala.math:

```
def pow(x: Double, y: Double): Double
```

Comment: It is an exercise. To have you practice using recursion. That is the whole point of any such assignment - to use a theoretical concept to solve a problem. Most problems can be solved in many different ways. Learning to program is about being able to apply most of these concepts in real source code.

Comment: It's an exercise. The goal is for you to learn something (recursion, here). Not to do something useful and as concise as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is asking to (re)implement a recursive pow function on integers:

```
def pow(x: Int, y: Int): Int = ...
```

You need write a smarter implementation than the naive `O(n)` algorithm:

```
def slowPow(x: Int, y: Int): Int =
  if (y == 0) 1 else x * slowPow(x, y - 1)
```

Try to use the given recursive definition instead...

To answer your question directly, I don't think you can dodge the question using the one from `scala.math`. As you noted it only works on `Doubles`. Also is neither recursive nor implemented in `Scala`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pow(x: Double, n: Int): Double = {
  if (n == 0) 1
  else if (n < 0) 1 / (x - n)
  else if (n % 2 == 1) x * pow(x, n - 1)
  else {
    val y = pow(x, n / 2)
    y * y
  }
}

pow(2, 0) == 1
pow(2, -2) == 0.25
pow(2, 4) == 16
pow(2, 5) == 32
```